# How to add a "File upload question" to a forms with Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been looking for a way of automating at work the google forms we need to create for Gsuite but [in this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) for the life of me I can't find how to add questions that allow me to have a file upload.

Like this image. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to programatically add this option to upload file in a form via Apps Script - there are existing issues logged with Google here:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72151985
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133389634 (marked as a duplicate of the first)

You can subscribe to this by clicking on the star ☆ next to the Issue number in order to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug.

I landed up here because when we reverse engineer it to see what type is Apps Script identifying form items that are created manually for the upload option, it gave out 'FILE_UPLOAD' which is not a documented ENUM per official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way -

```
function myFunction() {
  var frm = FormApp.openById('1TGGBsIC6NjZ9WScJHa4SvsRNmj4MaCOZGS_aLOEcD-8');
  var itms = frm.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.FILE_UPLOAD);
  var itm = itms[0];
  

  Logger.log(itm.getTitle());
  Logger.log(itm.getType());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JSAr.png)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**